# Finding Last Name of Hindi name from sql query(MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data base of eng and devnagri name like

---

**'PRABHU MATTHU RATHOD      | प्रभु मथथू राठोड'**

I am breaking these name as firstname ,middlename,lastname
Eng name is properly working but for hindi name it is showing issue

I have tried this to find last index of space in name

```
@MA_Name = प्रभु मथथू राठोड
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@MA_Name), 1,CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@MA_Name)) - 1));
```

here it is failing `CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@MA_Name)) - 1)` which is returning `-1`

 I dont know why

Answer (score 5):

Try using a `case` statement for exceptional names that don't have spaces.  Something like:

```
(CASE WHEN @MA_NAME LIKE N'% %'
      THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@MA_Name), 1,CHARINDEX(N' ', REVERSE(@MA_Name)) - 1))
      ELSE @MA_NAME
 END)
```

This assumes that without a space, the name is the last name.

EDIT:

The name may look like it has a space, but the space is a character other than `' '`.  You can figure out what it is by doing:

```
select ascii(substring(@MA_NAME, 7, 1))
```

(Or whichever is the right index for the space.)

Once you know what the character is, you can structure your query as:

```
(case when @MA_NAME like N'% %' then <what you have now>
      when @MA_NAME like N'%OTHERCHAR%' then <similar but with different space>
      else <whatever>
 end)
```

Comment: but this name has space .. i am not able to figure out why it is not working on some name

Comment: \u092a-->प
\u094d-->्
\u0930-->र
\u092d-->भ
\u0941-->ु
\u0020--> 
\u092e-->म
\u0925-->थ
\u0925-->थ
\u0942-->ू
\u0020--> 
\u0930-->र
\u093e-->ा
\u0920-->ठ
\u094b-->ो
\u0921-->ड these are unicode in hindi name **(\u0020) is for space**

Comment: @AlokTiwari . . . Maybe something is going wrong with compatibility between strings or collations or character pages.  Prepend all the string constants with `N` to be sure they are unicode

Answer (score 1):

This has been edited to combine what we've learned, so that it can be accepted as an answer, and can be useful to future visitors.

Consider this code:

```
declare @ma_name nvarchar(200) 
declare @r nvarchar(200)
declare @i int

select @MA_Name = N'प्रभु मथथू राठोड'  -- Thanks to Gordon Lindof for reminder to use N-prefix
set @r = reverse(@ma_name)

select @r

set @i = charindex(' ', @r )

select @i
```

The results are:

```
डोठार ूथथम ुभर्प
```

and

```
0
```

What appears to be happening is that the Reverse function is reversing the code points rather than the characters. To explain with just a substring of 4 code points:

```
\u0925-->थ \u0942-->ू \u0020--> \u0930-->र
```

u0942 is a combining character. The sequence u0925 followed by u0942 is a single character. REVERSE doesn't understand that and naively reverses the codepoints. The result is:

```
u0930 u0020 u0942 u0925
```

Now the combining character is attached to the space. So now it's not a space, it's a space with a whatever-that-is. (Sorry, don't know anything about Hindi, no disrespect intended.)

But CHARINDEX is not so naïve.  It sees that you are looking for a space, but it only finds the modified space character.

The poster has solved his problem by searching for the space using a FOR loop.

---

Here's some source that explains the situation:

```
-- CharList generates a comma-separated list of decimal values representing the list of nchar's
-- in an nvarchar.  In this context it's not important how it works.

if object_id('CharList')is not null drop function CharList
go
create function dbo.CharList(@c nvarchar(max))returns varchar(max)
as
begin
  declare @x varbinary(max)
  declare @h varchar(max)
  declare @i int
  set @x = cast ( @c as varbinary(max))
  set @h = ''
  set @i = 1
  while @i <= len(@x) 
  begin
    if @i > 1 
      set @h = @h + ','
    set @h = @h + cast(       cast(substring(@x,@i,  1)as int)
                        + 256*cast(substring(@x,@i+1,1)as int) as varchar)

    set @i=@i+2
  end
  return @h
end
go

-- For this code sample I'm going to use latin characters. (Sorry can't read Hindi.)
-- This string contains lowercase 'e' with an acute accent. 
-- In Unicode this can be represented two different ways.
-- It can be represented as a single codepoint: decimal 233.
-- Or it can be built from the letter 'e', followed by
-- the combining character for the acute accent: decimal 769
-- The purpose of this source is to demonstrate combining characters, so I'll use the
-- two-codepoint version.    

declare @m nvarchar(max)
set @m = N'Re' + nchar(769) + N'al'
select @m, dbo.CharList(@m)                 -- Réal    82,101,769,97,108

-- You see, the word 'Réal' consists of 4 characters, but is represented by 5 codepoints.

select charindex ( N'e', @m )               -- 0
select charindex ( N'e'+nchar(769), @m )    -- 2
select charindex ( N'é', @m )               -- 2
select charindex ( N'a', @m )               -- 4

-- CharIndex is smart enough to understand that. It understands that there is no letter 'e'
-- in this string of characters, even though the codepoint 101 appears in the string. 
-- It does find the letter 'é' when expressed with the two-codepoint version.
-- It will even find it when expressed as the single-codepoint version, even though
-- the codepoint 233 appears nowhere in the string.
-- And finally, it has no problem finding the 'a', but note that it returns 4.
-- 'a' is the 3rd character of the string, but appears at the 4th codepoint in the list. 

set @m = reverse ( @m )
select @m, dbo.CharList(@m )                -- láeR    108,97,769,101,82

-- Reverse is not as clever as CharIndex. It doesn't care about combining characters.
-- It just reverses the list of codepoints. 
-- Now the acute accent combining character appears after the 'a', and so the string now
-- shows the 'a' with the acute accent, and the letter 'e' has lost its accent. 

select charindex ( N'e', @m )               -- 4
select charindex ( N'e'+nchar(769), @m )    -- 0
select charindex ( N'é', @m )               -- 0
select charindex ( N'a', @m )               -- 0

-- Now, CharIndex will find a letter 'e' where there was none before. 
-- It can't find 'é' in either the one-codepoint nor two-codepoint forms, 
-- because it's not there anymore. 
-- A search for 'a' fails, because the string doesn't contain a plain 'a' anymore.
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue when i am pasting name directly on query it is returning 6 but when I am taking input from select query() for eg. (SELECT  @MA_Name = [NAME_MA] from [DICTIONARY_FULLNAME_EN_MA] where id = 1 ) it is returning -1

Comment: Can you tell me the collation of your database? SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = N'YourDatabase';

Comment: I think you are correct After reverse function it is not finding space  so I found last name by detecting last space using while loop..

Comment: @user1008646 . . . Let me see if I understand this.  Some the characters that I see are really the combination of two different characters and one of those characters could be attached to anything else.  `reverse()` then attaches it to the *wrong* character.  Has this been reported to Microsoft as a bug?

Comment: yes, some time it doesn't work after reverse(Devanagari word).

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I've added some more explanation.  Is it a bug?  It wouldn't hurt to report it to Microsoft, I'd bet they will describe it as working-as-designed.

Answer (score -1):

This is the type of problem (parsing and formatting) that is not always easy in SQL. In my experience, it's usually better to return raw data and let the calling/client program do all that string manipulation. It's often procedural in nature (thus not awesomely suited to set operations) and contains a lot of branching logic (which can be awkward in SQL).